# How to get all the video ids/urls from a youtube playlist if I have a playlist ID (in php)

Tags: php, regex, youtube

I am trying to get all the video ids/urls from a youtube playlist and store the same in a file-using php only.

I have used the following code to get the playist ids from the Playlists' url stored in the $youtube_url array:

```
foreach($youtube_url as $youtube_url) {
    $playlist_id = (preg_replace($playlist_pattern, '$1', $youtube_url));
    var_dump ($playlist_id);
}
```

The structure of the $youtube_url array is:

```
$youtube_url=array("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJTz1UbpSXM&list=PLguO-fOUIFtF5iuDmuVXJ_mjWDFZJNfCi",....)
//.... represents URLs of other playlists
```

Comment: Please show your `$playlist_pattern` and sample data you parsing.

Comment: Happy to help once the input has been added to the question.